# Why does density decrease most above Mach ~0.3, and not as much below Mach ~0.3 in fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, density

In fluid dynamics, why does the density of air decrease more above Mach 0.3, and not as much below Mach 0.3? From what I've heard, it isn't a linear relationship but why is that? Asked differently, what makes it a non linear relationship? I welcome a non-mathematical explanation, instead more of explaining what happens to the air molecules.

[Link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150977/discussion-between-wyatt-and-kyle-kanos) to chat for this question.

The last paragraph of [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/102499/70478) question has my guess of why the density doesn't change much below Mach ~0.3. It might be useful to see where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The non-linear relationship can be obtained from the conservation of momentum as,
$$\rho v\,\mathrm{d}v=-\mathrm{d}p\tag{1}$$
with $\rho$ the density, $v$ the velocity and $p$ the pressure. It also turns out that the pressure can be related to the density (assuming an isentropic flow, which describes a slowly changing flow rather than a very rapid change):
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{p}=\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\rho}\to\,\mathrm{d}p=\gamma RT\,\mathrm{d}\rho=a^2\,\mathrm{d}\rho\tag{2}$$
where we used the ideal gas law to eliminate $p/\rho$ and $a$ is the speed of sound.

Combining these two equations yields,
$$-M^2\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{v}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\rho}\tag{3}$$
where $M=v/a$ is the Mach number.

When $M$ is very small (e.g., much less than 1), the density is roughly constant as the left side of Eq 3 is approximately 0 due to the squared mach number. When $M\simeq1$, then the density increases at the same rate as the velocity and when $M\gg1$, then the density changes much faster than velocity.

---

On the intuitive side, what is happening is that some of the energy of the aircraft is being used to compress the air molecules in front/around it, which is then locally increasing the density. So this is really more of a "push" (by the airplane) than air molecules "bouncing" off each other as you describe in the linked question.

Comment: Would suggest "let $a$ be the speed of sound and let Mach number $M = v/a$" for clarity.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. If you read the 2nd paragraph of [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/57430/70478) answer, it says "speeding up is joined by a drop in density". So say that there is no aircraft and you speed the air up. Why does the density decrease in that case?

Comment: @Wyatt From what I can tell, that answer is talking about transsonic regimes where there can be shockwaves generated which can impact the density profiles; your original question is about subsonic flows. Somewhat an apples-to-oranges thing here.

Comment: I see. So if you just have air flowing in a container with no obstructions, what will happen to the density?

Comment: I thought Bernoulli's Principle stated that with speed comes a decrease in density, so that's what I was going off of.

Comment: @Wyatt No no no no! Bernoulli's principle says density is *constant*! It relates flow speed ($v$) with the area, pressure and height.

Comment: Haha I actually was going to edit my question, but I couldn't after 5 mins (edit to say pressure). So in that case, if you have air flowing with no obstructions, what will happen to the density?

Comment: What happens depends on too many variables. For instance, you could have shearing that leads to instabilities like Kelvin-Helmholtz. But probably for most subsonic flows you probably wouldn't see much other than fluid moving (e.g., no density change).

Comment: ah okay. But say you have a tube that contracts and then expands (e.x, rocket nozzle). Why does the middle part where it contracts have low pressure if there are no obstructions? Also, would you like to [continue this discussion in chat?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150977/discussion-between-wyatt-and-kyle-kanos).

Comment: Never mind, figured that part out. Last question, what would prove my original guess wrong? (of why density decreases as you speed up). thanks. (you can also answer this in chat if you'd like)